# Why is the Notifications from firebase_messaging either comes twice or doesnt come at all?

Tags: flutter, notifications

Hi I am using firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16 plugin to send push messages on my phone by following the steps in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfTrbKtnvTo.

The problem is either I dont get the notification or get two notifications of the same message twice simultaneously.I am using the cloud messaging and when I actually selecte "expanded view" it is only then I start getting notifications.Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix this?Any other way for push notificatios would be equally welcomed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWRym.png)

Comment: 1 - Why you don't receive the notification I don't know, something is wrong, maybe in your code. 
2 - Whenever you receive a cloud message, it will be called twice, this is an [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1669) with no answer until this moment.

Comment: Try to send a notification to on your device FCM Token and then check if the issue persists.

Comment: @Haroon khan,I am very sure I am doing what ur saying.U might have a look at the video might as well for better understanding,because I exaclty did what was told there